# /run/udev/tags/ on a Kubuntu VM: Cannot remove 'snap_firefox_firefox' after uninstalling Firefox. What are these files?

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu, snap

I am trying to completely uninstall Firefox in a VM, which I did via:

```
snap disable firefox
snap remove --purge firefox
```

But an FSearch query turned up the following:

[image]

There is next to nothing on the web when I search for this. How do I remove these residual snap references? What are these files / references?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/blog/a-guide-to-snap-permissions-and-interfaces) about snap permissions will help you

Snaps are self contained software packages. Each package is sandboxed so that it runs in a constrained environment, isolated from the rest of the system. To then allow a package access to common resources, the snap system provides ‘interfaces’ to which packages can be granted access as required or determined by the user. This includes hardware devices.

In your case the `drm:card0*` entries are related to the linux graphics subsystem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager))

> The Direct Rendering Manager (DRM) is a subsystem of the Linux kernel responsible for interfacing with GPUs of modern video cards

For the other three entries `c*:*` I cannot really say but I would guess that it is something similar

Regarding removing those you should use snap disconnect

`snap disconnect <snap>:<plug interface> <snap>:<slot interface>`

more info in the Interface management [manual](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the explanation. I'll go ahead and try your suggestion of `snap disconnect...`